# Convert any URL into a relative URL

Tags: javascript, url

There are many questions and answers about changing relative URLs in to absolute URLs, but I need to do the opposite.

Given these URLs...

```
www.example.com/some/page
example.com/some/page
http://www.example.com/some/page
https://www.example.com/some/page
http://www.example.com/some/page
http://www.example.net/some/page
```

How could I reliably extract the URL paths relative to the root URL?

Comment: The problem is that there are unknown factors. How would you know that the root is not `http://www.example.com/mapping/`?